# Adding field in Mongoose plugin gives "TypeError: Invalid value for schema path `CreatedBy.type`"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript, mongoose, mongoose-plugins

I'm trying to make a CreatedBy Mongoose plugin, but when trying to use the `ObjectId` as the field type it gives me (`"account"` is another defined collection already):

```
TypeError: Invalid value for schema path `CreatedBy.type`
```

& here is the plugin code:

```
mongoose =  require 'mongoose'
module.exports = exports = updatedByPlugin = (schema, options) ->
  schema.add CreatedBy:
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    ref: "account"
  schema.pre "save", (next) ->
    @CreatedBy = options.accountId
    next()
    return

  schema.path("CreatedBy").index options.index  if options and options.index
  return
```

So how I can modify the `ref` value to make it work?

Comment: You should tag this with the appropriate language tag (coffeescript?).

Comment: But it has nothing to do with Coffeescript, if the code was written in JavaScript, it could have done the same

Comment: So a question about pointers in C should be tagged only pointers, not C? If it were written in C++, it could be the same problem after all. The goal is to cast as wide a net as possible. Someone who follows the coffee script and mongoose tags can probably more easily help you than someone who follows JS and mongoose. The change in syntax requires a bit of mental readjustment. Your solution may even have to do with how coffee script compiles, although it is more likely that you changed something else along the way. (All my JS mongoose models have type then objectId.)

Comment: Asking about a specific package is not about the language itself, but since it won't hurt, I added it anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you won't believe it, but I solved it by adding the `CreatedBy` field this way

```
schema.add CreatedBy:
   ref: "account"
   type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
```

Yes, by just exchanging the 2 lines for `ref` & `type`!! . It is weird how exchanging these 2 lines could break the code :| !!!

Comment: Still, in 2018, this is the solution.