# Mongoose throw new TypeError no matter WHAT I do

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a simple app based on this [thinkster.io MEAN stack tutorial](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/).

My posts.js code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    link: String,
    upvotes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
});

// methods for post
PostSchema.methods.upvote = function (callback) {
    this.upvotes += 1;
    this.save(callback);
}

mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

Here is the error:

```
throw new TypeError('Invalid value for schema path `'+ prefix + key +'`'
        ^
TypeError: Invalid value for schema path `post.type`at Schema.add 
(/Users/macbookpro/flappernews/flapper-news/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:205:13)
```

What I've done: Used a completed repository to edit/reference the other files in case the error is related to something outside of Posts.js.
Repo reference:https://github.com/lepazmino/flapper-news

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you could narrow this down further. What's this `post.type` thing?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26531815/269300. Try reordering the `ref` and `type` properties in your `comments`.

Comment: @PatrickMcLaren I reordered the ref and type properties in comments, same error is thrown.

Comment: @Anko looked in to post.type *sighs*.The routing contains a config block and a posts controller? Maybe referencing the wrong post (Post, posts, post).  If the controller injects the posts service, could the schema path be related to that? not sure if I'm remotely close. The search continues...